# automating android CTS with python

Tags: android, python, scripting, automation, cts

I'm trying to automate the full CTS setup and execution with python & monkeyrunner on Ubuntu and most of it has gone very well.  As the very final step, I try executing the following python command to start the CTS on a specific device:

```
cts_tradefed_script = "./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed"
process = subprocess.Popen([cts_tradefed_script, "run", "cts", "-s", '"' + serialno + '"', "--plan", "CTS"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed run cts -s "R32CB054TSZ" --plan CTS
```

in the command-line and I get:

```
Android CTS 4.2_r4
No commands for non-interactive mode; exiting.
06-17 17:32:32 I/: Detected new device R32CB054TSZ
Saved log to /tmp/tradefed_global_log_9173619073367947049.txt
06-17 17:32:32 I/CommandScheduler: All done
```

The CTS tests don't execute.  Is there a command I'm forgetting or is this not possible using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cts_tradefed_script = "./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed"
process = subprocess.Popen([cts_tradefed_script + " " + serialno], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Edit: script was not necessary.  Just enter everything as a concatenated String.

Comment: have you automated the full CTS? How did you created a new plan. i am stuck at creating a new plan based on failure of earler run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with non-interactive is that you cannot run more than a command, so you should try to run in interactive mode.

To run in interactive mode this is one way:

```
#pip install paramiko
import paramiko
import time

def run_remote_command(channel, command):
  channel.send(command)
  whole_output = ""
  while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
      output = channel.recv(1024)
      whole_output+=output
    else:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      if not(channel.recv_ready()):
        return whole_output

server ="fill you own here"
username = "fill you own here"
password = "fill you own here"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, 22 ,username, password)
channel =ssh.get_transport().open_session()
channel.get_pty()
channel.invoke_shell()


run_1 =run_remote_command(channel,"~/android/out/host/linux-x86/cts/android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed list devices" + "\n")
print run_1

run_2 =run_remote_command(channel,"run cts" + "\n")
print run_2

run_3 =run_remote_command(channel,"l i" + "\n")
print run_3
```